# QGIS - Add a combobox to a toolbar

Tags: qgis, python, qt

Is there a way to add a combobox to a toolbar for QGIS? So far I can only find examples that add buttons.

I found [this tutorial](http://www.commandprompt.com/community/pyqt/x4974.htm) which seems to explain how to do this with general PyQT but haven't had any luck at all doing this with QGIS. So any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have achieved it by adding the following to the initGui method of my main python file.

```
self.toolBar = self.iface.addToolBar("My Toolbar")
self.toolBar.setObjectName("My Toolbar")

self.projCombo = QComboBox(self.iface.mainWindow())
self.projCombo.addItem('item 1')
self.projComboAction = self.toolBar.addWidget(self.projCombo)
self.projCombo.setToolTip("My Combo Box")
```

Comment: Literally just reading a tutorial on the addWidget function. Exactly what I needed and works fine. Thank you very much

Comment: @James S Thanks to your answer, I've managed to add a list of my layers to the combo box. Strange thing is, the combo box isn't populated unless I reload the plugin. Any ideas? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93230/custom-toolbar-combobox-issues-with-adding-functionality